# Amazon Certificate Manager - Validation issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate

I created a new certificate for my new domain(bought in GoDaddy) with Amazon Certificate Manager 
and for verification I choose Email based and I didn't receive any verification email now. It's been more than 2 days . Not sure how to debug this ? any ideas ?

Thanks
Venkat

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not Amazon or GoDaddy support. Contact them.

Comment: Check if your email addresses are provided to ACM correctly!
"AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) sends email to the 3 contact addresses listed in WHOIS and to 5 common system addresses for each domain that you specify. That is, up to 8 email messages will be sent for every domain name and subject alternative name that you include in your request." see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-validate-email.html